# Selenium browsers not recognized if using phpunit.xml

Tags: php, phpunit, selenium-webdriver

I've created a test case by extending \PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase and specifiying the browsers using $browsers, in phpunit 3.7.21:

```
class SeleniumTest extends \PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
{
    public static $browsers = array(
        array(
            'name' => 'Explorer on Windows',
            'browserName' => 'explorer',
            'host' => 'localhost',
        )
    );
}
```

But if I remove $browsers and try to configure the browsers in phpunit.xml by putting the following in the  tags, as per the [docs](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/appendixes.configuration.html),
the settings do not get read:

```
<phpunit
    bootstrap="../../TestModule/test/ModuleBootstrap.php"
    backupGlobals="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="manager">
            <directory>./Test</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <selenium>
        <browser name="Firefox on Windows"
           browser="firefox"
           host="localhost"/>
        <browser name="Explorer on Windows"
           browser="explorer"
           host="localhost"/>
    </selenium>
</phpunit>
```

I've tried changing `browser="explorer"` to `browserName="explorer"` but in either case the settings are not getting picked up.

I believe it is not a connection issue as PHPUnit does not try to run the test for each browser. Is this feature supported in PHPunit / Selenium2?

Comment: Could you past the whole phpunit.xml?

Comment: Sure thing, I've added it to the original post.

Comment: The example in the [docs](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.selenium-rc) extend PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase rather than PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase, so I am wondering if this is the reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `phpunit.xml` solution only works for `Selenium RC` (and it's stated explicitly in the documentation).

For phpunit selenium 2 you have to follow your original idea with a static property.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for clarifying - I'm finding the Selenium naming conventions slightly confusing! In that case I'll settle for adding a constant for the selenium server address in phpunit.xml.

Comment: Well, it's not overly explicit, it says `The <selenium> element and its <browser> children can be used to configure a list of Selenium RC servers.` and that's it...could be more clear, maybe `...can only be used to configure...`

Comment: Link to that quote: http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.selenium-rc

Comment: Also note that Phing does not support the `<selenium>` tag.  May or may not apply to your situation.